# compiler (clang, android ndk r18) can't find stl_algobase.h

Tags: android-ndk

Trying to compile something since the update of the ndk to r18 gives me the following error:

```
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `/...../toolchains/arm/21/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../include/c++/4.9.x/bits/stl_algobase.h', needed by `something.o'.  Stop.
```

Looking manually for the folder "bits" showed that it is not there. So, of course, there is this error, because the compiler can't find 'stl_algobase.h'.

As far as I know now "gnustl, gabi++, and stlport have been removed." (https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/wiki/Changelog-r18) So "The shared library version of libc++ will be used by default." (https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain#c_stl_support)

I'm using the clang++ & clang compiler of the standalone toolchain and the following flags:

```
CXXFLAGS        := -fPIE -fPIC
CXXFLAGS        += -std=c++14
```

Note:

1) Using 'CXXFLAGS      += -stdlib=libstdc++' it is the same.

2) I tried 'CXXFLAGS        += -stdlib=libc++' too, but then the compiler will give this extra error: 'fatal error: 'vector' file  not found'

My first thought is that the stl isn't linked properly, for some reason. Most likely there is some flag missing or the installation of the standalone toolchain was wrong. Here is how I did it:

```
sudo /...../Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/build/tools/make_standalone_toolchain.py --api 21 --install-dir /...../Developer/toolchains/arm/21 --arch arm --force --verbose
```

If it is something that I was thinking of it could be, how to do it right? Or is it maybe something different that I did not think of? How to properly use libc++ in an external makefile with Android NDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `make clean` or whatever your project's equivalent is. You have stale dependency files in your out directory.

Comment: That's it! But could you tell me, how did you know/find that? The error message did not let me think of that.

Comment: No rule to make target pointing from one of your object files to a header that doesn't exist is a pretty good indication of a stale dep file.